# Google Maps - Discover order of points for the lower route

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need a way to find out what the best route between points using the Google Maps API.

Assuming I have four points A, B, C and D, and I'll go from point A, need to figure out what the best sequence should I visit and plot the points on the map the smallest route to this sequence.

From what I researched in the API documentation, it is easy to find the lowest route between multiple points, but the API expects the order of points. In my case I need the API to return me the best order.

The solution that I thought was to find all possible ways, then find the shortest route to all of them and then show this route. But this solution will not have good performance and the Google API has limited the amount of routes that can draw in a day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use: [{optimizeWaypoints: true}](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints)

```
you may pass optimizeWaypoints: true within the DirectionsRequest to allow the
Directions service to optimize the provided route by rearranging the waypoints
in a more efficient order. (This optimization is an application of the 
Travelling Salesman Problem.) All waypoints must be stopovers for 
theDirections service to optimize their route.
```

[fiddle with {optimizeWaypoints: false}](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/q67Lcnsj/)

```
var start = "New York, NY";
var end = "New York, NY";
var waypts = [];
var wayptsIn = ["Montreal, QBC", "Toronto, ONT", "Chicago,IL", "Winnipeg,MB", "Fargo,ND", "Calgary,AB", "Spokane,WA"];

for (var i = 0; i < wayptsIn.length; i++) {
    waypts.push({
        location: wayptsIn[i],
        stopover: true
    });
}

var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: false,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

[same fiddle with optimizeWaypoints: true}](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/zs5mce1w/)

```
var start = "New York, NY";
var end = "New York, NY";
var waypts = [];
var wayptsIn = ["Montreal, QBC", "Toronto, ONT", "Chicago,IL", "Winnipeg,MB", "Fargo,ND", "Calgary,AB", "Spokane,WA"];
for (var i = 0; i < wayptsIn.length; i++) {
    waypts.push({
        location: wayptsIn[i],
        stopover: true
    });
}

var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

Comment: This is what I need, but have to set beyond the original destination point. Do you know if you can perform this calculation also optimizing the destination point?

Comment: It only works for the waypoints.  Perhaps make a circular route that has the same start and end point, see if that gives you the results you need.

Answer (score 1):

Study your data for clues...
This problem is known as the 'Travelling Salesman Problem' and there is no known method that is better than the brute-force exhautive-search method you mention  [Look up 'NP-complete' for the computer-science aspects].
You can beat the system only if you employ 'extra' knowledge about the routes, (such as the order, as Google expects), which you might be able to get from your 'insider' application knowledge. Only that will give you an opportunity to reduce the number of searches.
Good luck!

Comment: I know the traveling salesman problem, but in this case the idea is to determine the best route out of a point A visiting various points and coming back to a point A. In my case I will not go back to point A, need to find the best point end.

Answer (score 1):

Use this optimizeWaypoints: true

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints