# Order with directionsService - google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers

I have a problem with the near order.
I have an array of objects:

```
waypoints = [
 location:{
 lat: -8.116597,
 lng: -79.0347417
},
location:{
 lat: -8.120997,
 lng: -79.038355
},
location:{
 lat: -8.120151,
 lng: -79.037014
},
location:{
 lat: -8.119195,
 lng: -79.036657
},
]
```

in this way I send to google maps:

```
this.$refs.mapa.$mapCreated.then(() => {
          this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
          this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.$refs.mapa.$mapObject);
          this.directionsService.route({
            origin: { lat: -8.0828174, lng: -79.0953881 },
            destination: this.waypoints[this.waypoints.length - 1].location,
            waypoints: this.waypoints,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING',
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
          }, (r, status) => {
              if (status === 'OK') {
                this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(r);
                console.log(r.routes[0].waypoint_order);
                }
            });
        });
```

In which should bring me the closest points of the origin and if it does. The problem occurs when I make changes in the order of sending the array of objects. For example, if I order, I print the following order:

```
[0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
```

but if I change the order of the arrangement and then order it, print another order:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5]
```

I do not know why this happens because you do not have to import the shipping order if not the positions(lat, lng)

Is something missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `origin` and `destination` are fixed in the request.  `optimizeWaypoints` only optimizes the order of the waypoints.

Your code is using one of the "waypoints" as the destination.

Related question:

- [Google Maps - Discover order of points for the lower route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176507/google-maps-discover-order-of-points-for-the-lower-route)

Comment: then should I remove the destiny?

Comment: A destination is required.